# How to check a series of numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am making a digital vault lock with javascript where users need to fill in four numbers in the right order to unlock something on the page.

The page consists of a textbox where they fill in a number under 10 and push a button to send the number. They have to do this 4 times and if the numbers and the order are correct (4 5 2 7 for example), it will unlock and a picture will show.

I tried to make it work with a "if" structure, but cant seem to think of the right way to do this.

```
function checkingcombination (){
      if(numberpushed == 4){
        if(numberpushed == 5){
          if(numberpushed == 2){
            if(numberpushed == 7){
               alert("lock unlocked, welcome");
            }
            else{
             alert("wrong combination");
             return;
            } 
          }
          else{
           alert("wrong combination");
           return;
          }
        }
        else{
          alert("wrong combination");
          return;
        }
      }
      else{
        alert("wrong combination");
        return;
      }
}
```

Comment: When will `if(numberpushed == 4) { if(numberpushed == 5) { ... }}` ever pass?

Comment: you probably dont wanna do it with if statements. Think about a for loop

Comment: `numberpushed` is morphing ...

Comment: You can collect pushed button/numbers in one array and check it on every change/keypress.

Comment: From what I can tell you are looking at this problem as someone who usually works with programming languages that support synchronous IO.

In JavaScript you cannot wait for the next keypress the way you would need to make this work. You need to store a state (e.g. the count of numbers which have been sent) and check on a submit event or something.

Comment: I hope this is just for fun and not anything important, as they can just view source to see the code.

Comment: The javascript is actually on a node.js server. Im doing this with a arduino and hardware, but yeah its nothing too important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have something like this (based in your description):

```
<input type="number" id="digit"><button onclick="checkingcombination();">OK</button>
```

You could do something like this:

```
var digits=[];
function checkingcombination() {
    var input=document.getElementById("digit");
    var digit=input.value;

    //TODO validate digit

    //store each digit in the array
    digits.push(digit);

    //once there are 4 digits stored, check if the code is valid
    if(digits.length==4) {
        var correctAnswer=[4,5,2,7];
        if(digits.join("")==correctAnswer.join("")) {
            alert("lock unlocked, welcome");
            return;
        } else {
            alert("wrong combination");
        }
        //clear digits to enter a new combination
        digits=[];                
    }

    //clear the textbox to enter the next digit
    input.value="";
    input.focus();
}
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver thanks, this was exactly what i needed. Im doing this with arduino hardware and node.js and i just dont have the basic coding skills to come up with this. But it works thanks to you, i can now use my hand and a ultrasonic sensor to unlock something in my browser. This saved me a sleepless night! Thanks to all the others too, but because im doing this with an ultrasonic sensor most of those ways wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
function checkingcombination (array){
  var rightCombo = [4,5,2,7];

  for(i = 0; i<userCombo.length; i=++){
    if(userCombo[i] !== rightCombo){
        alert('"' + userCombo[i] + '" is wrong number!');
        return false;
    } else {
        alert('Right combo!');
        return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use if statements you will need to have your function take some arguments. You will need to pass the values from the inputs on the HTML page into the function.  Something like this!

```
function checkingcombination (firstNumber, secondNumber, thirdNumber, fourthNumber) {
  if(firstNumber == 4){
    if(secondNumber == 5){
      if(thirdNumber == 2){
        if(fourthNumber == 7){
           alert("lock unlocked, welcome");
        }
       ...


var firstNumber = document.getElementById('firstNumber').value;
var secondNumber = document.getElementById('secondNumber').value;
var thirdNumber = document.getElementById('thirdNumber').value;
var fourthNumber = document.getElementById('fourthNumber').value;


function validate() {
  checkingcombination(firstNumber, secondNumber, thirdNumber, fourthNumber)

}
```

in your html you will need inputs that those query selectors can reference by those IDs

```
<input id="firstNumber" type="number">
<input id="secondNumber" type="number">
<input id="thirdNumber" type="number">
<input id="fourthNumber" type="number" onkeyup="validate()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is my solution.

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="9" class="vault-value" />
<input type="number" min="0" max="9" class="vault-value"/>
<input type="number" min="0" max="9" class="vault-value"/>
<input type="number" min="0" max="9" class="vault-value"/>
<button onclick="validateLock()">VALIDATE</button>

<div>
  <label>Result: </label>
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var validaCombination = [1,2,3,5];
function validateLock(){
  var vaultElements = document.getElementsByClassName("vault-value");
  var valid = true;
  for(var i =0; i< vaultElements.length; i++){
    var vaultElement = vaultElements[i];
    var combinationValue = validaCombination[i];
    if(combinationValue !== parseInt(vaultElement.value)){
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  valid ? showSuccess() : showError();
}

function showError(){
  var resElement = document.getElementById("result");
  resElement.innerHTML = "Error!";
}

function showSuccess(){
  var resElement = document.getElementById("result");
  resElement.innerHTML = "Success!";
}
```

Example:
http://codepen.io/xszaboj/pen/NdjLNo?editors=1010

Explanation:

You take the values from inputs and match them agains the validaCombination array. If all values match, it is the correct combination otherwise it is error

Security advice

I hope this is just a fun project and not something serious. Because everybody can read you combination and check your "secret numbers".

Answer (score 0):

Despite the massive security flaw of this app, I am assuming you are just trying to learning so I will ignore that.

When you run a if statement, it will check the logic is true and run the code inside ONLY if it is true. So basically, the rest of your if statements are getting ignored.

Lets think of another way to do this. Lets say you create 2 arrays. One is the actual combination and the other is the trial. Only when your trial is equal to the same length as the correct combination, then and only then, it will run a function.

When the function is ran, it appends your current input text to the trial array, resets the text in the text box and next checks the length of trial and compares it to combo.

You have to click the button 4 times and you will get a message. If it is not the same, the trial array is wiped clean.

This would be a good time to open your developer tools and look at type in the console the name of your variables and look at them each time you click.

## HTML

```
<label for="combo_submit">Enter number:</label>
<input type="text" id="combo_input">
<button type="button" id="combo_button">Click Me!</button>
```

## Javascript

```
<script>
    var input = document.getElementById("combo_input");
    var button = document.getElementById("combo_button");

    var combo = [1,2,3,4];
    var trial = [];

    button.addEventListener("click", checkComboNumber);

    function checkComboNumber() {

        var number = Number(input.value);

        trial.push(number)

        input.value = "";
        input.focus();

        if (trial.length === combo.length) {
            if (combo === trial) {
                msg = "Well... im impressed";
            } else {
                msg = "Stop trying to guess!";
                trial = [];
            }
            alert(msg);
            console.log(msg);
        }
    }


</script>
```